# How can I update a user flag in rules?

Tags: rules, flags

I am using a user flag, **Visits**, to track each user's visits to other user's profiles.

When a user visits another user's profile, a rule is triggered that automatically flags the visited user on behalf of the visiting user.

Flagging the user on the first visit is no problem.  But **on the second visit and thereafter, I want to update the flag that was flagged on the first visit.**  To do this, I made the following rule:

- Event: User account page is viewed
- Condition 1: NOT `[account]` is `[site:current-user]`
- Condition 2: User is flagged (`[account]` on behalf of `[site:current-user]`)
- Actions-> **How do I fetch and update the flag?**

This rule is triggered correctly; however, I don't know how to get the previous flag (the flag applied when the user visited the profile for the first time) in order to update it.

My question: how can I fetch the previously applied flag in rules so that I can update the timestamp and re-save it?

**What I tried**

Flag provides a rules action **Fetch user flagged by user**, but this does not help because this returns an array of users, not the flagging, which is what I want to update.

I can add the **Unflag a node** action and then the **Flag a node action**, but this will destroy my previous flag and replace it with a new one; since I want to track referer information over time, this is not a good solution.

Since I'm using Flag 3.x in which flags are entities, I tried using the **Fetch entity by property** action in Rules to fetch the *flagging*, but in this case the only property I can choose to select is the value of the **Referer** field, which is not helpful.  There seems to be no way to fetch the flag by its endpoints.

**Why I'm doing this**

This flag has a computed field, **Referer**, which stores the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` upon flagging.

When a user visits the profile of a user for the second time, I want to update this flag by updating the timestamp of the flagging and adding the new referer information to the flag.

Comment: I am going to assume Flag 3.x where flags are now entities.  If so, is there another path or action through Rules outside of Flag that could operate upon this entity?

Comment: @Jimajamma Yes, I'm using Flag 3.x.  Good point, since flags are entities, it may be possible to use the entity integration in Rules.

Comment: The limitation with flag is it can only be flagged and unflagged (if flagged). So, its boolean on/off. I gave up using flag in such situations and looked for VotingApi. Specially the voting plusOne module (https://drupal.org/project/plus1). I am not sure if it has rules integration, if it has then it'd solve your problem.

Comment: Why don't you simply unflag the visited user and flag him/her again afterwards? In that way, you don't have to mess around with timestamps of the old flag.

Answer (score 2):

> My question: how can I fetch the previously applied flag in rules so
>   that I can update the timestamp and re-save it?

Some good news but mostly bad.

If you add an extra text field to the flag and add an extra rule to set its data value to `[flagged_uid]-[flagger_uid]` when a flag is created, it *seems* that you can then fetch the flagging using that field as the Property and `[account_uid]-[current-user_uid]`.

I say *seems* because while the rule runs without errors and I know my logic is right, I can't do anything to the fetched flagging to prove I've actually fetched it. I get an error when trying to delete it because "Rules doesn't have info about deleting a flagging" and saving it doesn't change the timestamp.

It just feels like it's not fully integrated. Even if you added a date field, I'm not sure Rules could access it on user view.

---

I guess I would either create a custom rules action to finish the rule or go with a fully fledged [Field Collections](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a count field to the flag entity (a numeric field).  Every time a user visits a profile, grab the flag and +1 to the count field.

Unfortunately I would not be able to answer how you get this flag via the rules UI.

You could create a custom rule (in code), or a user view hook (hook_user_view).  Within this hook, load the flag and update the count value.

The below code is an example of the idea, I havent tried it myself.  If it doesn't work, try a different flag load and save method.  (if no other better method is found you could even resort to a database query to load and update the flag).

```
HOOK_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode){
  if ($view_mode == 'profile') {

    // Get user id's
    global $user;
    $viewing_uid = $user->uid;
    $viewed_uid = $account->uid;

    // If we are not viewing our own profile
    if ($viewing_uid != $viewed_uid) {

      // Load the flag contents // Remember to check entity name, and field names
      $flag_entity = entity_load('user_flag', FALSE, array('uid' => $viewing_uid, 'content_id' => $viewed_uid));

      // Update the count
      $flag_entity->count = $flag_entity->count + 1;

      // re-save the entity
      $return = entity_save('user_flag', $flag_entity);
    }
  }
}
```

As a side note: If you have a problem displaying the flag contents on page/profile views, you could also use a load/view hook to override what is displayed.  As its an entity however, the field should be available via the entity view mode or views.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping to do this in Rules, but based on your example I tried to do it in code.  However, I wasn't able to load the flag via `entity_load()`. It seems that `EntityFieldQuery()` is preferred to `entity_load()` anyway: "Instead, it is preferable to use EntityFieldQuery to retrieve a list of entity IDs loadable by this function." https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7